# dynamic page title - after json render

Tags: json, document, title

The head is already generated in my document, and then the page is passing a url parameter and getting a response with json data - based on that json data, I need to change the page title (I'm assuming there's not a method to get SEO benefit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the title by javascript;

```
document.title = "Page Title";
```

Comment: right, so I dynamically assign the page title based on another element on the page.